# How to get list of all views in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm trying to configure autocomplete input with all created blade views so is there option to get an array of all views? There is View::exists() to check for specific view but how to get all of them?

```
public function index(){   
$allviews = Storage::files('');     
return view('pages.dashboard', ['allviews' => $allviews]);  
}
```

In my view I have this code

```
@foreach($allviews as $view)
<li>{{ $view }}</li>
@endforeach
```

It only shows **.gitignore** file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `File` facade to scan the directory and give content of it.
check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#directories

configure your view disk in `config/filesystems.php` add below snippet in **disks array** :

```
'disks' => [

    // ...

    'views' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path('resources/views'),
    ],
],
```

`Storage::disk('views')->files('') //will list all directory and contents available in resources/views`

`Storage::disk('views')->files('auth') //will give content of resources/views/auth directory`

Comment: you need to switch your disk i am updating answer

Comment: thanks :) to make the views disk default update your config/filesystems.php and set views as default disk then you can ommit disk('views') stataement